# Google maps linked to d3 chart

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, tooltip

On my page I have a Google map and a bar chart, which is drawn using d3. When I hover over the bar chart the opacity changes and a tooltip appears. What I'm trying to do is this same thing but trigger it from the map. Therefore, when you hover over a marker in the map the corresponding bar in the bar chart is highlighted (i.e. opacity changes and a tooltip appears).

In my bar chart I've called the tip function, as below, but I don't know how to trigger this from the map markers?

```
tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {
return hrTip(d);
})
```

Has anyone come across this problem before please?

Answer (score 0):

Marker class supports a bunch of events:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

You can add listeners to your markers using google.maps.event.addListener() function.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

E.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    //Implement your logic here
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (event) {
    //Implement your logic here
});
```

Comment: I've used this to trigger a function but it's implementing that function is where I'm having trouble. I don't understand how to trigger the tooltip in the graph from this function.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.